# Unable to interact with nodes on web with a angular app

Tags: angular, corda

I Referred the letter of credit cordapp cordapp which does the same i copied the dist contents and placed it in resource but when start my spring server in my cordapp and navigate to my node's port i am unable to see the ui can anyone help regarding this.

I get 404 error somehow my port is getting picked by my angular app I used window.location.href to interact with my exposed api in my cordapp and to make use of dynamic url since there are 3 nodes and all have different port's .

here is corda api file content:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/trading/") // The paths for GET and POST requests are relative to this base path.
class MainController(rpc: NodeRPCConnection) {

    companion object {
        private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestController::class.java)
    }

    private val myLegalName = rpc.proxy.nodeInfo().legalIdentities.first().name
    private val proxy = rpc.proxy

    /**
     * Returns the node's name.
     */
    @GetMapping(value = "me", produces = arrayOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
    fun whoami() = mapOf("me" to myLegalName)

    /**
     * Returns all parties registered with the network map service. These names can be used to look up identities using
     * the identity service.
     */
    @GetMapping(value = "peers", produces = arrayOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
    fun getPeers(): Map<String, List<CordaX500Name>> {
        val nodeInfo = proxy.networkMapSnapshot()
        return mapOf("peers" to nodeInfo
                .map { it.legalIdentities.first().name }
                //filter out myself, notary and eventual network map started by driver
                .filter { it.organisation !in (SERVICE_NAMES + myLegalName.organisation) })
    }

    /**
     * Displays all IOU states that exist in the node's vault.
     */
    @GetMapping(value = "trades", produces = arrayOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
    fun getTrades() : ResponseEntity<List<StateAndRef<TradeState>>> {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(proxy.vaultQueryBy<TradeState>().states)
    }

    /**
     * Initiates a flow to agree an IOU between two parties.
     *
     * Once the flow finishes it will have written the IOU to ledger. Both the lender and the borrower will be able to
     * see it when calling /spring/api/ious on their respective nodes.
     *
     * This end-point takes a Party name parameter as part of the path. If the serving node can't find the other party
     * in its network map cache, it will return an HTTP bad request.
     *
     * The flow is invoked asynchronously. It returns a future when the flow's call() method returns.
     */

    @PostMapping(value = "create-trade", produces = arrayOf("text/plain"), headers = arrayOf("Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))
    fun createIOU(request: HttpServletRequest): ResponseEntity<String> {
        val counter = request.getParameter("counterParty")
        val tradeStatus = request.getParameter("tradeStatus")
        val userId = request.getParameter("userId")
        val assetCode = request.getParameter("assetCode")
        val orderType = request.getParameter("orderType")
        val txDate = request.getParameter("transactionDate")
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
        val transactionDate = sdf.parse(txDate)
        val transactionAmount = request.getParameter("transactionAmount").toDouble()
        val transactionFees = request.getParameter("transactionFees").toDouble()
        val transactionUnits = request.getParameter("transactionUnits").toDouble()
        val transactionPrice = request.getParameter("transactionAmount").toDouble()
        val transactionId = request.getParameter("transactionId")
        if (counter == null) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Query parameter 'Counter partyName' missing or has wrong format")
        }
        if (transactionAmount <= 0 ) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Query parameter 'Transaction Amount' must be non-negative")
        }
        val partyX500NameCounter = CordaX500Name.parse(counter)
        val counterParty = proxy.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(partyX500NameCounter) ?:
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Target string \"$counter\" doesn't match any nodes on the network.")

        val producer = Producer()
        return try {
            val signedTx = proxy.startTrackedFlowDynamic(TradeFlow.Initiator::class.java,tradeStatus,counterParty,userId,assetCode,orderType,transactionAmount,transactionFees,transactionUnits,transactionId,transactionDate,transactionPrice).returnValue.getOrThrow()
            val mapper = JacksonSupport.createNonRpcMapper()
            val result = mapper.writeValueAsString(signedTx)
            producer.send(result)
            ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("Transaction id ${signedTx.id} committed to ledger.\n")
        } catch (ex: Throwable) {
            logger.error(ex.message, ex)
            producer.send(ex.toString())
            ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(ex.message!!)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays all IOU states that only this node has been involved in.
     */
    @GetMapping(value = "getTrade", produces = arrayOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
    fun getTransactionDetails(@RequestParam("linearID") linearID: String): ResponseEntity<List<StateAndRef<TradeState>>>? {
        if (linearID == null) {
            ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Linear Id cannot be null.\n")
        }
        val idParts = linearID.split('_')
        val uuid = idParts[idParts.size - 1]
        val criteria = QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(linearId = listOf(UniqueIdentifier.fromString(uuid)),status = Vault.StateStatus.ALL)
        return ResponseEntity.ok(proxy.vaultQueryBy<TradeState>(criteria=criteria).states)
    }
```

here is my angular 6 app.route.ts file:

```
    import { LandingPageComponent } from './Landing-Page/landing-page/landing-page.component';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";


    const APP_ROUTES:Routes=[
        {
             path:'', component: LandingPageComponent
         }
    ]


export const APP_ROUTES_PROVIDER = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

The landing page has the ui content that i should see while interacting with my nodes

here is my service file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions,URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable()
export class CordaContentService {
  payload;
  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  private trades = new Subject<any>();

  // Observable string streams
  tradeMethodCalled$ = this.trades.asObservable();

  getAllTrades() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.http.get('http://localhost:50005/api/trading/trades',{
     headers: headers
   }).pipe(map((res : any)=>res.json()))
   .subscribe(
    (res) => {
     this.payload = res;
     console.log('success');
     this.trades.next();
    }
   );
   }
```

I call this getAllTrades function from the ngoninit section of the app.component.ts class but when i enter this url i get http 404 error.
i ran this command and copied the dist folder content into my cordapp resources folder
ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer
Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you look at the rest url directly instead of via the angular app? Can you see any other pages from the angular app? Is the angular app deployed properly? Which port is your node started on? How are you connecting to it from your kotlin class? Are you using the right port there? Any error messages? Any stack traces? Any logs? There is not enough info here to help effectively.

Comment: When I look the url directly from postman I get the results I followed the process as mentioned in the letter of credit cordapp. I am using my node 's port .I have mentioned the rest api defined  there.

Comment: My port is 50005 I don't see anything ideally my landing page component should load on this url http://local host:50005 as mention in route.ts file but I don't see anything

Comment: "i copied the dist contents and placed it in resource" - copied which dist into which resource directory?  "but when start my spring server in my cordapp" - the spring server isn't _in_ your cordapp, it is a separate jar. Are you packaging with Spring Boot? Are you running the rest api and web page together as a Spring bootJar? Or something else?

Comment: No there are grade tasks to run the server I am just running that sorry I may have mis pronounced and as faR as the dist folder thing is converted chk this https://github.com/corda/LetterOfCredit/blob/release/README.md#updating-the-web-frontend I did this

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information from the above and comments, I think you might have used the wrong url in angular app.

Typically, if you have your spring server started correctly and call the correct the API, you will not see a 404 page not found error message.

I would suggest you take a look the example here: https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/blob/master/Advanced/obligation-cordapp/clients/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/training/server/MainController.kt